# requiring and then compiling html in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of templates in an AngularJS controller which display depending on which array item is selected like so:

```
function controller() {
    vm.templates = [
        { name: 'form1200intro.html', url: require('html-loader!../html/europct/europct.form1200.intro.tpl.htm')},
        { name: 'form1200questions.html', url: require('html-loader!../html/europct/europct.form1200.questionnaire.tpl.htm')},
        { name: 'form1200generated.html', url: require('html-loader!../html/europct/europct.form1200.generated.tpl.htm')}
    ];
}


$scope.form1200Template = vm.templates[0].url;
```

And in the html I am displaying them using the `ng-bind-html` directive, like so:

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="form1200Template">
</div>
```

The HTML is loading but none of the expressions are compiling.

**Question**

How do I display the html with all expressions compiled?